# What type and color of car

Tags: sentence-construction

What type and color of car is it? 
It's a blue monster truck.

Is the question well composed for the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads a little strange having a describing word, but not immediately knowing what is being described.  "What is the car type and color?" makes it clear earlier in the sentence what is being described, though it feels slightly awkard to me as well.  Hmm.  Maybe just the wordy "What type of car is it and what is its color?" may be best.

That said, you are asking for a "car" type and answering with a "truck", which is not quite the same thing.  In this case, using the noun "vehicle" would better describe the answer you have.

"What is the vehicle type and color?" could be answered as you have it now without any disagreement.

Comment: I disagree a little with what you said about _vehicle_. If someone told me, "Michele will be picking you up around six," I wouldn't ask, "What kind of vehicle does she drive?" Rather, I'd probably say, "What kind of car does she drive?" The person might answer, "She drives a green pickup," but I'm not going to blush because I said "car" instead of "vehiicle." The place where I get my license plates renewed might use _vehicle_ instead of _car_, but, in day-to-day conversation, _car_ is often used for this question.